Apache custom ErrorDocument throwing phantom error when Redirect 200 is active
I've been struggling with this issue for the past three days and don't seem to be getting any closer to the solution.
Scenario:
Apache 2.4.58 (official Debian-based docker container)
What I want to do:
in case of 404 Not Found I want to return a custom static html page (this is working flawlessly) BUT I also want to return that page with a status 200 - OK instead of 404 (this part is driving me nuts).
I found plenty of guides here on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and all boil down to basically this:
Redirect 200 /error404.html 
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html 

Easy-peasy, right? Not quite:
When I just add the ErrorDocument directive and request a non-existing resource it serves the custom doc with a 404 Not found (as expected):
curl -vvv https://example.com/doesnotexist.html 

[...] 

> GET /doesnotexist.html HTTP/1.1  

> Host: example.com  
> User-Agent: curl/8.6.0  
> Accept: */*  
>  
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  
< Date: Thu, 30 May 2024 09:52:53 GMT  
< Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Unix) OpenSSL/3.0.11  
< Last-Modified: Tue, 28 May 2024 09:48:25 GMT  
< Content-Type: text/html  
<  
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact  
<html><body><h1>This is my custom 404 error</h1></body></html> 


And this gets written in the logs:
[Thu May 30 09:52:53.947402 2024] [core:info] [pid 9:tid 139907934459584] [client 1.2.3.4:27247] AH00128: File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/doesnotexist.html  
1.2.3.4 - - [30/May/2024:09:52:53 +0000] "GET /doesnotexist.html HTTP/1.1" 404 51  
[Thu May 30 09:52:54.028838 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 9:tid 139907926066880] ssl_engine_io.c(1147): [client 1.2.3.4:27247] AH02001: Connection closed to child 1 with standard shutdown (server example.com:443)  

But as soon as I add Redirect 200 /error404.html this is what I get:
curl -vvv https://example.com/doesnotexist.html 

[...] 

> GET /doesnotexist.html HTTP/1.1  
> Host: example.com  
> User-Agent: curl/8.6.0  
> Accept: */*  
>  
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  
< Date: Thu, 30 May 2024 10:20:52 GMT  
< Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Unix) OpenSSL/3.0.11  
< Content-Length: 315  
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1  
<  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">  
<html><head>  
<title>404 Not Found</title>  
</head><body>  
<h1>Not Found</h1>  
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>  
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found  
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>  
</body></html>  
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact  

But the logs say that I'm actually returning 200 OK:
[Thu May 30 10:26:26.591783 2024] [core:info] [pid 15:tid 140127749695168] [client 1.2.3.4:1475] AH00128: File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/doesnotexist.html  
1.2.3.4 - - [30/May/2024:10:26:26 +0000] "GET /doesnotexist.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/8.6.0"  
[Thu May 30 10:26:26.672210 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 15:tid 140127758087872] ssl_engine_io.c(1147): [client 1.2.3.4:1475] AH02001: Connection closed to child 132 with standard shutdown (server example.com:443)  

Summarizing:
The ErrorDocument directive is working, the custom error document exists and can be served to the client.
The Redirect 200 directive seems to be working too, since Apache logs say "GET /doesnotexist.html HTTP/1.1" 200
The actual output, though, is a 404 error that says "a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument" but no such error is logged.
What am I missing here?
